# How to make a label text with modified radio size in-line

Tags: html, css, razor

I have radio button that has a label however the result that I got is that the text is not in-line and that texts breaks new line between the words. The following is the code:

```
                <div class="form-group  col-sm-4 ">
                    @Html.RadioButton("FlatFile", false, new { @style = "height:55px; width: 35px; inline" })
                    @Html.Label("Material Master", new { @style = "height:55px; width: 55px; checkbox-inline" })
                </div>
```

and the result I got:

[image]

The expected result is that the sentence  "Material Master" should be in one line. How can I do this.

Comment: Most likely it is wrapping because the width of your "form-group col-sm-4" div is too small.

Comment: I have tried with " col-sm-4 col-md-4  col-lg-4" but with no result

Comment: The text become like that since I have changed the size of the radio button

Comment: I have also tried with bigger numbers but does not work

Comment: I suggest double check the css width of the radio label then, most likely there or the div... work backwards to isolate the width limits.

Comment: I have increased the size of the text width now the text is inline but the only problem that I got from this that I ended up with having the text under or near the edge of the radio button